# ColdFusion 9's ODBC Socket Datasource issue on Tomcat 7

Tags: iis, tomcat, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Recently, I installed CF9 web app on Tomcat 7 build 22. I get the CF9 server up running fine on Tomcat 7. Everything works flawlessly, except one thing I really need, failed badly (see below please):

What I installed:

1. Installed CF9 with WAR selection and all sub-components checked on Win 7 32bit.
2. Installed CF9 update to 9.0.1
3. Deployed CF9.WAR on Tomcat 7 without an issue.
4. From CF Admin Manager, adding MS SQL Server without an issue. Also adding another Embedded Derby server fine.
5. The issue occurs when adding a data source for ODBC Socket type. The error messages are:

   > `Error accessing available odbc datasource - Unable to load library
   >   The ColdFusion ODBC Server service is not running or has not been installed`
6. I tried reinstalling CF9 again 2 times just to make sure everything was selected properly but NO luck. Same issue with ODBC Socket data source.
7. From Component Service Manager, CF9 ODBC Server is running, but there is no 'CF9 ODBC Agent' listed.
8. There is no way I could get CF9 ODBC data source on Tomcat.

Now, to make it works, I have to install and deploy CF9 on IIS 7.5 server on the same machine. The difference is both CF9 ODBC Server and Agent appearing and running on Service manager.

One more test:

And now I decided to stop IIS server and CF9 on IIS. I then started CF9 on Tomcat, everything works fine except for the same ODBC Socket datasource issue. What I noticed is the "CF9 ODBC Agent" disappeared from Service Manager.

The result is both CF9 on Tomcat AND CF9 on IIS now have same ODBC Socket data source issue. (Due to the disappearance of ODBC Agent)

To get CF9 ODBC data source back running on IIS server, I have uninstalled CF9 from IIS server, then reinstalled CF9 on IIS server. Now, it is working again, I can see both CF9 ODBC Server and Agent listed and running on Service manager.

My goal is to try to get CF9 on Tomcat 7 along with ODBC data source functioning. But NO LUCK so far.

Please HELP:

If anyone has CF9 deployed on Tomcat, please do me a favor by just entering any ODBC data source name with ODBC socket selection and HIT 'ADD' to see if it works. I doubt it would not work, because I have tried on the other machine at home. STILL NO LUCK :(.

If no one else can get it to work on Tomcat, then it is an Adobe CF9 issue and should be either handled in the next HOTFIX or in the next version release.

Please help me check for this issue.

Thank you & have a nice weekend.
Ben Nguyen

Comment: As a server issue rather than code, you might get better responses at [sf].

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the bug you've stumbled upon: http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/79023

Comment: I think the bug report points to the solution indirectly. Installing the documentation should ensure the proper directories are created. Then you can uninstall/reinstall the ODBC services using the admin api. For an example, download `odbcInst.zip` and see the `installODBC.cfm` script (only) - do not install any of the other files. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402637.html . Though it is worth noting Tomcat probably is *not* officially supported - yet. Awarding the bounty for pointing in the right direction ;-)